# DOMException claiming WebUSB interfaces

Tags: arduino, webusb

I've read similar questions others have had in using FTDI (CDC Class) and WebUSB, however none of the suggested answers have worked for me.

I'm trying to communicate to an Arudino Mega via:

```
 this.device_.selectConfiguration(1)
 this.device_.claimInterface(0); // or  this.device_.claimInterface(1);
```

but I get a DOMException.. and chrome://device-log shows the device in blue ("USB user").

I know Chrome must use an interface that is not bound or attached to Windows, however, the USBconfiguration shows 2 interfaces, both not claimed, and yet I can't claim either.

Despite trying to uninstall and use WinUsb.sys, Windows always loads the ftdiport.sys driver NOT WinUsb.sys.   Not sure what could be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The two interfaces are listed as unclaimed because your page hasn't claimed them. Whether or not there is another application or driver on the system claiming the interface is not reflected in the API.

Fighting with Windows to not load `ftdiport.sys` may be a losing battle. I am working on implementing the [Serial API](https://wicg.github.io/serial/) in Chrome which should offer a better solution for this class of devices. Alternatively, have you tried installing the WinUSB driver with the [Zadig tool](https://zadig.akeo.ie/)?